# How to perform async.each in async .series

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

In my function i have to call async series inside async foreach to compute the final result and create my json.is that possible

```
 async.series([
       function(callback) {
        });
         },
function(callback) {
        async.forEachSeries(temp,function(quest,callback) {

        }, function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
        });
        callback();
    }
],
    function(err) { 
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(output);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to nest as much async functions into each other, however it is better to use a naming conventions so you can easily track which callbacks are passed where and to avoid collisions due to hoisting. So basically this should work as you'd expect:

```js
async.series([
  function first(seriesCallback) {
    seriesCallback();
  },
  // other functions in series
  // ...
  function (seriesCallback) {
    var someArray = [];
    async.each(someArray, function (value, eachCallback) {
      // process the value
      // return an error if there is one
      eachCallback(err);
    }, function(err) {
      // add any additional processing you might need
      // pass the control to the parent async method and handle the errors
      // in a more central place if there is an error here it will
      // be processed in onSeriesDone as well as all other errors
      seriesCallback(err);
    });
  }], function onSeriesDone(err) {
    next(err);
  });
```